# server client :socket programming

Tags: linux

i am using Linux fedora 2.6.by using server client (socket) programming ,the LISTEN system call how many connections server accept(default :how many clients) once.

Regrds venkat

Comment: What is the question? Consider rephrasing.

Comment: accept() is the call you mnake after your create a listener.

Comment: maybe you would know something more about the `backlog` parameter of `listen`: `int listen(int sockfd, int backlog)`. If so, please take a look at `man listen`.

Answer (score 0):

accept creates a new socket every time it gets a new connection. The limit to the number of new connections is OS depdendent

You are limited by the number of available file descriptors.  Each socket uses one file descriptor. From the command line  `ulimit -a` will show you how many are available, inside code you can call getrlimit() with RLIMIT_NOFILE  to find the total possible of file descriptors your process can open.